# How does the horizontal menu scroll work in the Gilt Group iPhone App?

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, horizontalscrollview

The Gilt iPhone app uses UIScrollView and UIPageControl to page through their content, but I was wondering how they implement their horizontal scrolling menu at the top.

[image]

Is it a UITableView rotated -90 degrees? 
How does it know that the center item should be set as selected? 
Is it a UIScrollView with buttons and maybe you check if the button is in a certain region, it selects that button and uses the scrollToRect method?

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: Did u get any way to do so? Because i would like to implement this kind of menu in my app

Comment: djblue2009 : Didi u find any idea on this ?